Dividir código en dos archivos en C++ como lo haría la sentencia call en batch
Quisiera saber si hay forma de dividir el código de C++ en dos archivos pero sin tener que pasar variables, como si fuera todo el código seguido en el mismo archivo.
Esto lo puedo hacer en batch así:
archivo1.bat
@echo off
set numero=7
call archivo2.bat
echo %numero%
pause

archivo2.bat
set /a numero=%numero%+1

resultado
8

Lo más parecido que he conseguido hacer es creando variables globales en el archivo principal y creando variables externas en un archivo de encabezado.

ok, creo que se puede hacer algo parecido con archivos .h algo asi como una libreria externa ... igual tendrias desde un archivo hacer el include

Bienvenido. Verás: bat es un lenguaje de script y C++ es un lenguaje de programación. Es posible que la solución propuesta no sea exactamente lo que esperabas. No queda otra que aprender a usar las herramientas que tienes.

Te sugiero usar los archivos de cabecera, son los que tienen extensiones .h o .hpp. Permiten definir clases, funciones, macros y otras entidades que se pueden incluir en múltiples archivos fuente, mejorando la legibilidad, mantenibilidad y reutilización del código.
Estructura básica de un archivo de cabecera:
#ifndef NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO
#define NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO

/*
  Declaraciones de clases, funciones, macros, etc.
*/

#endif


#ifndef NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO: Esta línea verifica si el archivo de cabecera ya ha sido incluido previamente. Si no ha sido incluido, se continúa con la compilación.

#define NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO: Esta línea define una macro con el nombre del archivo de cabecera. Esto permite evitar conflictos de nombres si se incluyen varios archivos con el mismo nombre.

/ ... /: Esta sección contiene las declaraciones de clases, funciones, macros y otras entidades que se desea exponer a los archivos fuente que lo incluyan.

#endif: Esta línea indica el final de la protección contra inclusiones múltiples.


Ejemplo de uso:
Supongamos que tenemos tres archivos: clase_persona.h clase_persona.cpp y main.cpp. El archivo clase_persona.h define una clase Persona con sus atributos y métodos:
#ifndef CLASE_PERSONA_H
#define CLASE_PERSONA_H

class Persona {
public:
  Persona(const std::string& nombre, int edad);
  std::string getNombre() const;
  void setNombre(const std::string& nombre);
  int getEdad() const;
  void setEdad(int edad);

private:
  std::string nombre;
  int edad;
};

#endif

En el archivo clase_persona.cpp se implementa o define el código de archivo de cabecera.
#include "clase_persona.h"

Persona::Persona(const std::string& nombre, int edad) {
  this->nombre = nombre;
  this->edad = edad;
}

std::string Persona::getNombre() const {
  return this->nombre;
}

void Persona::setNombre(const std::string& nombre) {
  this->nombre = nombre;
}

int Persona::getEdad() const {
  return this->edad;
}

void Persona::setEdad(int edad) {
  this->edad = edad;
}

Explicación:
Archivo clase_persona.h:
Se incluye la protección contra inclusiones múltiples (#ifndef ... #define ... #endif).
Se declara la clase Persona con sus métodos públicos (getNombre(), setNombre(), getEdad(), setEdad()) y atributos privados (nombre, edad).
Archivo clase_persona.cpp:
Se incluye el archivo de cabecera clase_persona.h para acceder a las declaraciones de la clase.
Se definen las implementaciones de los métodos de la clase Persona:
Persona::Persona(const std::string& nombre, int edad): Constructor que inicializa los atributos nombre y edad.
std::string Persona::getNombre() const: Devuelve el valor del atributo nombre.
void Persona::setNombre(const std::string& nombre): Establece el valor del atributo nombre.
int Persona::getEdad() const: **Devuelve el valor del atributo edad.*"
void Persona::setEdad(int edad): Establece el valor del atributo edad.
En el archivo main.cpp, se incluye el archivo de cabecera clase_persona.h para acceder a la clase Persona y crear objetos:
#include "clase_persona.h"

int main() {
  Persona persona1("Juan", 30);
  persona1.getNombre(); // Accediendo al método getNombre()

  return 0;
}


Los archivos de cabecera (.h o .hpp) solo declaran las clases, funciones y macros, mientras que los archivos de implementación (.c o .cpp) contienen las definiciones y el código real de las funciones.

Organización: Dividir el código en archivos de cabecera permite una mejor organización y modularidad del proyecto.

Reutilización: Las declaraciones en archivos de cabecera se pueden incluir en múltiples archivos fuente, evitando la duplicación de código.

Legibilidad: La estructura clara de los archivos de cabecera mejora la legibilidad del código.

Mantenibilidad: Los cambios en las declaraciones se realizan en un solo lugar (archivo de cabecera), facilitando la mantenibilidad del código.

Utilizar protecciones de inclusión anidadas: Si un archivo de cabecera incluye otros archivos de cabecera, use protecciones de inclusión anidadas para evitar conflictos de nombres.


Espero ser de ayuda.
